# Class method to modify and set class member variable

Tags: c#

I would like to have a class method that modifies the existing member variable and sets the modified value.

Example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string color { get; set; }

    public string getColor
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
    }

    public string convertColor
    {
        set
        {
            this.color = this.colorConversion();   
        }
    }

    public string colorConversion()
    {
        string number = this.getColor;
        switch (number)
        {
            case "0":
                return "Lighter";
            case "1":
                return "Good!";
            case "2":
                return "Darker";
            default:
                return "Fix this somehow!";
        }
    }

}
```

So when I instantiate the object, I would only need to use one line to do the conversion

Such as:

```
Animal cow = new Animal();
cow.convertColor;
```

Rather than have multiple lines such as:

```
Animal cow = new Animal();
string currentColor = cow.getColor;
cow.setColor = cow.colorConversion(currentColor);
```

Please help me understand if it is possible.

Comment: Those `getColor` and `setColor` 'methods' aren't necessary - the `color` property itself already has a getter and setter. Also, ignoring the given `value` in a property setter is... not what other programmers would expect. Is a string really the right type here? `"Friday"` is a valid string, but it's not a valid color... Either way, why does `Animal` need to convert from numeric strings to color names - and what sort of relationship is there between those numbers and color names?

Comment: Whoops, thank you for catching these! :-)

The string type is because I'm getting the string return value (of a number) from an api and I need to convert it to a string in a different format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you only want one or the other:

```
public string color { get; set; }
```

**OR**

```
public string getColor
        {
            get
            {
                return color;
            }
        }
```

You are mixing two things here, one has immutability `getColor` and the other has mutability `color` so you need to decide whether you want the end user to be able to `get` or `get and set` the property.

Secondly, you want to convert the color when you instantiate the class.... This is weird because when you instantiate the class, `color` will be an empty string and have **no color**.

Thirdly, if you use the constructor to new up a class and pass the color in - like so `new Animal("blue")` - then why convert it when you get from the property, because now you are obscuring the function of this property to the end user. This doesn't follow the principle of least astonishment.

So what you could do is abstract the conversion away from the class to make it more obvious.

```
class AnimalColorConverter
{
    public void ConvertColor(Animal animal)
    {
        animal.color = colorConversion(animal.color);
    }

    private string colorConversion(input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "0":
                return "Lighter";
            case "1":
                return "Good!";
            case "2":
                return "Darker";
            default:
                return "Fix this somehow!";
        }
    }
}
```

Then your lines would become:

```
var converter = new AnimalColorConverter();
var animal = new Animal();
animal.color = "1";
converter.ConvertColor(animal);
```

What you also need to consider is brevity isn't always a good thing, when you come back to this one liner in 6months time, will you understand what it is doing?

Finally, if I haven't understood what your class is trying to do and haven't answered it perfectly - that's because from your code I can't understand what you are trying to achieve, which refers back to the 6month problem. When writing code you should practise naming things exactly what they do, and if the name is too long, it's trying to do to much (separation of concerns part of the SOLID principles).

So from my code, I have a class called `AnimalColorConverter` which is nearly there in terms of describing what the function of this class is. Then I have a method called `ConvertColor` which is also fairly close to describing what this function does. I could name them better, if I knew what `"0"` represented in your `switch` statement. I assume that `"Lighter"` is a grade of the color. So I could have named my function `ColorGrader` and then I would expect the grade of the color to come out.